# WCF Restful multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am new in WCF Restful service, I am creating a service with two different methods,one have single parameter and another have multiple parameters.
These are my service methods

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Test", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Response Test(string p_user);
```

I am consuming the above method in asp.net like this

```
string service_url = "http://localhost:5022/MyService.svc/Test";
var p_data=txtBox1.Text;//Passing the parameter
            string result = string.Empty;
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(service_url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(p_data);
            request.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;
            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
                postStream.Close();
            }
            StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var response = js.Deserialize<ServiceResponse>(result);
```

It is working fine, now I have another method with multiple parameters like this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Test2", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Test2(string a, string b);
```

how can I pass multiple parameters with using the same code of consuming? ie How should I make p_data for this method?
I have tried using UriTemplate = "Test/{a}/{b}" and UriTemplate = "Test?a={a}&b={b}", but I am getting bad not found in first and bad request in second case.

Also I want to ask,how can I debug the service methods?

Comment: Debug? Start with debugging and place a breakpoint? When you call the service, it will stop and you will be able to debug.

Comment: Template `Test?a={a}&b={b}` is the right way to call and should work.

Comment: @GregaMohorko can you tell me how can I create p_data for this case?may be I am passing it wrongly?I am doing this var str = "a=10&b=15"; and  then serializing it

Comment: I just saw you are using POST, not GET, sorry. I don't know how to manage post requests in such way. Why are you not using the service as a client and simply calling the methods? Would be 2 lines of code ...

Comment: It is the requirement